# Play 2.5 Scala DI :play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf replacement

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection

In Play 2.5

`play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf(classOf[UID])` is deprecated.  How does one achieve dependency injection on a variable.

Is there a replacement.
I tried.

```
Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule).getInstance(classOf[UID])
```

But that throws several exceptions related to dependency injection. ( I have MyAppModule present and also have module enabled in conf file)

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Inject' annotation as described in the docs? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. Why do you need injector instead of using @Inject annotation to access some instances?

Comment: @Inject annotation on fields is not working. The variable continues to remain null.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your field? In what entity (controller, model, etc) are you trying to inject?

Comment: you can't inject a static final field
in other cases there is no problem

Comment: i am trying to inject a var field in scala. play.api.Play.current.injector.instanceOf works, but anything else does not.

Comment: If field injection is not working, then I'd rather try to solve that than trying to find an answer here on how to work around it. You can surely request the instance manually, but this is a very bold red signal in your code. Think about testability.. In any case, constructor injection is actually preferred to field injection.

Comment: Another possible use-case: I'm using @Inject everywhere in the application, and it's definitely the correct way, but got to situation where I'd like to inject WebJars into the templates. This is currently not supported (2.5.8, on the roadmap though) and I'm really not liking having the WebJars injected into every controller and then passed to every template as argument. Until the injection into the template is supported, I'd prefer to decouple the app/business logic from WebJars and retrieve instance of WebJars from the Injector directly in the template.